# How to update notification display from inside a function

Tags: android, flutter, dart, just-audio, audio-service

I'm using audio_service and just_audio on my flutter app which is a radio player and
I'm having trouble updating the mediaItem on the notification.

When I call mediaItem.add(item) from within play() or pause() it works fine
but when I try the same from inside a function (the one I use to modify the mediaItem in the first place) it doesn't update

code examples :

```
  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
    mediaItem.add(item);
    _player.play();
  }
```

There it works, the notification shows the updated item

but if I call :

```
updateMediaItems(String album, String title, String artist, String coverUrl) async {
    
      item = MediaItem(
        id: 1,
        album: album,
        title: title,
        artist: artist,
        artUri: Uri.parse(coverUrl),
      );
    }
    mediaItem.add(item);
}
```

The item itself is correctly updated but not displayed in the notification
If someone can help me understand where is the issue, I been looking around and tried a lot but didn't get it (it's my first app using flutter)

UPDATE :

I just tried to call the function from inside my play() function like so :

```
@override
  Future<void> play() async {
    updateMediaItems('','test title','','default');
    _player.play();
  }
```

And by doing so it works.

LAST UPDATE

I tried calling the function from inside my AudioHandler class and it works. It seems the problem was that I was calling it from my PageManager class. I don't really get why, if someone can explain it to me it'll be nice but at least I got it to work

Comment: Are you making sure to use await keywords on future functions?

Comment: I just tried without the Future part and still no luck. I'll update my code in the question

Comment: You have to await the updateMediaItems

Comment: await updateMediaItems('', 'test title', '', 'default');